# How to convert curl to python requests

Tags: python, curl, facebook-graph-api, python-requests

I'm using facebook api to create ads.

I have next curl:

```
curl -G \
-d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<PRODUCT_CATALOG_ID>/product_sets
```

And I want to use it with python `requests` library. I try as follows:

```
data = {
   'access_token': user_token
}

response = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/{0}/product_sets'.format(catalog_id), data=data)
```

But when I execute it I get an error:

```
{'error': {'message': '(#100) The parameter name is required', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 100, 'fbtrace_id': 'AcUg6UZivr_rNWgkwdEHaZl'}}
```

But when I execute the `curl` I get correct response.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need to make a `POST` request? Because `-G` flag means make a GET request.

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G

```py
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{API_VERSION}/{PRODUCT_CATALOG_ID}/product_sets'.format(
    API_VERSION='v3.3',
    PRODUCT_CATALOG_ID='catalog_id123'
)
res = requests.get(url, params={
    'access_token': 'my access token'
})
res.raise_for_status()
data = res.json()
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that I've used `post`. That is it. Thanks.